# Need help format the naming of a PDF created from Google sheets

Tags: windows

Can I format the date and time in this code?

```
const wsInputPdfName = "Unit Registration-Unit # " + wsInput.getRange("Q12").getValue().toString() + "-" + Date.now().toString() + ".pdf";
```

Result:

```
Unit Registration-Unit # 244-1698245816918.pdf
                       “Q12”-Date Now()
```

But it should be:

```
Unit Registration-Unit # 244-10/23/23.pdf
                       “Q12” Date Now() in date format
```

Also another form.

```
const wsInputPdfName = "Crew Change " + wsInput.getRange("AB1").getValue().toString()+ wsInput.getRange("G10").getValue().toString() + "-" + Date.now().toString() + ".pdf";
```

Result:

```
Crew Change La100Mon Oct/23/2023 02:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)-1698245847648
```

But it should be:

```
Crew Change La100-10/24/23-12:00
        “AA1”+:G10”+   ”Z10”
```

Can I format the date and time in this code?

Just the current code.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. What language are you using? From your tag of `windows`, I cannot understand your situation. What is `“AA1”`, `:G10”`, ”Z10” of `Need Crew Change La100-10/24/23-12:00 “AA1”+:G10”+ ”Z10”`? Do you want to remove `".pdf"`? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.